# Stripping column values by large string of words in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, lambda, strip

I've got a dataframe that has many columns but has a column of States that have extra strings attached to them. The column looks like this:

```
State
U.S. Natural Gas Number of Residential Consumers (Count)
Alabama Natural Gas Number of Residential Consumers (Count)
Kentucky Natural Gas Number of Residential Consumers (Count)
Mississippi Natural Gas Number of Residential Consumers (Count)
Tennessee Natural Gas Number of Residential Consumers (Count)
Arizona Natural Gas Number of Residential Consumers (Count)
Colorado Natural Gas Number of Residential Consumers (Count)
Idaho Natural Gas Number of Residential Consumers (Count)
Montana Natural Gas Number of Residential Consumers (Count)
Nevada Natural Gas Number of Residential Consumers (Count)
New Mexico Natural Gas Number of Residential Consumers (Count)
.
.
.
```

I'd like to get rid of `Natural Gas Number of Residential Consumers (Count)` from each value so that I'm only left with the State. I've tried:

```
df['State'] = df['State'].map(lambda x:x.strip('Natural Gas Number of Residential Consumers (Count)'))
```

But this doesn't seem to work. It gives me this as an output:

```
State
U.S.
A
Kentucky
Mississipp
T
Ariz
""
Idah
M
v
w Mexic
.
.
.
```

When I want to strip single characters like `R` this does work - tested it using `x.rstrip` and `x.lstrip`.

Is mapping using the lambda function the right way to strip these long strings from all my values? I'm not sure what the best way is for doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try [replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html), followed by strip:

```
df['clean'] = df['State'].str.replace('Natural Gas Number of Residential Consumers (Count)', '', regex=False).str.strip()
print(df.clean)
```

**Output**

```
0            U.S.
1         Alabama
2        Kentucky
3     Mississippi
4       Tennessee
5         Arizona
6        Colorado
7           Idaho
8         Montana
9          Nevada
10     New Mexico
Name: clean, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another more simple way too. Rather than using map, make use of Apply:

```
df['State']=df['State'].apply(lambda x:x.split(sep='Natural')[0])
```

The reason I am giving " Natural"(means a space before Natural), so that it doesn't add a whitespace in the final outcome. This gave me following output:

```
        State
0   U.S.
1   Alabama
2   Kentucky
3   Mississippi
4   Tennessee
5   Arizona
6   Colorado
7   Idaho
8   Montana
9   Nevada
10  New Mexico
```